# How to type a returned Array inside an Array?

Tags: typescript, tuples, namedtuple

```
return [[x, y], d, prevRing, prevRingPosition]
```

That is my return statement and I want to make a type for its function

```
type nextUlamReturn = [
  number[],
  d: number,
  prevRing: number,
  prevRingPosition: number
]
```

But this gives me the error:

`Err: Tuple members must all have names or all not have names.`

I've searched a lot in the internet but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the error message is hard to understand. You don't have a name for the first element (the number array), but do for the others. Add a name for that element and it should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array? You can return an object with named properties like:

```
type nextUlamReturn = {
  numbers: number[],
  d: number,
  prevRing: number,
  prevRingPosition: number
};

const test: nextUlamReturn = {
  numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  d: 10,
  prevRing: 10,
  prevRingPosition: 10,
};
```